# Nested pairs using operator hyphen

Tags: prolog

I want to represent edges as pairs using the hyphen operator, i.e., `From-To`.
I want to represent nodes as pairs as well (denoting FCA concepts), i.e., `Extent-Intent`.
So I get something like the following:

```
([1]-[a])-([2,3]-[b])
```

The brackets make sure the expression is properly disambiguated: the single outer hyphen denotes the edge operator, the two inner hyphens denote the node operator.

Here is my problem:

```
?- X = (a-b)-(c-d), X = Y1-Y2-Y3.
X = a-b- (c-d),
Y1 = a,
Y2 = b,
Y3 = c-d
```

I was expecting this to fail instead...
My questions:

1. **Why are the brackets removed in the (displayed) binding of `X`?**
2. **Why is the first hyphen interpreted in a different way than the third one?**

Possibly relevant, precedence rules for the hyphen operator:

```
?- current_op(P,T,-).
P = 200,
T = fy ;
P = 500,
T = yfx.
```

(This is in SWI-Prolog developer branch, but I doubt this will be SWI-specific.)

Comment: For completeness, the official name for such a minus pair is `pair`. You can see this from the error message for `keysort([a],_)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, `write_canonical` is very useful in understanding how Prolog interprets operators.

```
?- write_canonical(a-b-c).
-(-(a,b),c)
true.

?- write_canonical(a-(b-c)).
-(a,-(b,c))
true.

?- write_canonical(a-b-c-d).
-(-(-(a,b),c),d)
true.

?- write_canonical(a-b-(c-d)).
-(-(a,b),-(c,d))
true.
```

And then, this sort of makes sense, assuming that all hyphens here are binary operators with the right hand argument having the strictly lower precedence:

```
?- X = (a-b)-(c-d), X = Y1-(Y2-Y3).
X = a-b- (c-d),
Y1 = a-b,
Y2 = c,
Y3 = d.

?- X = (a-b)-(c-d), X = (Y1-Y2)-Y3.
X = a-b- (c-d),
Y1 = a,
Y2 = b,
Y3 = c-d.
```

The first brackets are not strictly necessary to display the nested term `-(-(a,b),-(c,d))`. The second pair of brackets is necessary, otherwise it would mean `-(-(-(a,b),c),d)`.

PS. Since I am not good enough to always keep operator precedence rules in my head, I try to avoid operators. There is nothing wrong with explicit functors. The hyphen of course is very useful for predicates like `keysort/2` and libraries like `library(ugraphs)`.